# How to list the directories non recursively which are 30 days older

Tags: unix, find

I want to list the folders in UNIX which are older than a month. I have tried the following options:

```
find . -type d -mtime +30
```

Which will list files recursively however I want non recursive one.

Comment: What do you mean, "non-recursively"?  Have you tried `-depth` to limit how far `find` will delve?

Comment: Yes, but i do not know the syntax for depth. Could you give me the syntax? I tried with the following line, please check find . -type d -mtime +30 -depth 1

Answer (score 3):

Add the `maxdepth` option:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +30
```